# How to populate an html page using data from a SQL table

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I want to populate an html page using data from a SQL table... data will be categorized based the year

Table will look something like this:

```
Year  Month   article 
-----------------------
2010  Jan     Sql101  
2010  Feb     Html101  
2010  Mar     Smsht101  
2011  jan     test101
```

I want the output to look something like this

```
2010
Jan sql101
Feb html101
Mar smsht101 

2011
Jan test101
```

What is the easiest method to do this? I'm fairly new to ASP.NET.

Maybe using a repeater?

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/zzx23804(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Which version and flavour of asp.net are you using? Repeaters only exist in the legacy Web Forms flavour. I wouldn't recommend learning that if you're new, it's yesterday's technology